# Compile C++ project using python script from visual studio 2005

Tags: python, visual-studio-2005, scons, visual-studio-extensions

I've a big project with C and C++ code ,we are using Scons to build it from command line .Is there any plugin for VS 2005 to run python script for comiple ,run and debug from IDE itself.

Comment: Try to use method from here http://www.scons.org/wiki/IDEIntegration.

Comment: Thanks,I've tried that but in my case scons uses both GCC and Visual studio compiler , compilation is not successfull